# Rails3 CSV putting &quot;&quot; instead of actual quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, fastercsv, html-safe

*Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885687/ruby-on-rails-csv-putting-quotquot-instead-of-actual-quotes) except I don't use `html_safe` anywhere in the whole project.*

I generate a CSV file in `index.csv.erb` like this:

```
<%=
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
CSV.generate do |csv|
  @persons.each do |person|
    csv << [ person[:name], person[:nickname] ]
  end
end
%>
```

**PROBLEM:** If nickname is NULL in the database (ActiveRecord/MySQL) then the CSV file associated element becomes `&quot;&quot;`. I would expect `""`, or even nothing at all.

Result file sample:

```
Nicolas, Nico
Joe, &quot;&quot;
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using `html_safe`. Your nickname field is blank and converted to `""` in the csv file, but it is deemed unsafe by Rails and html escaped.

Just call `html_safe` on the result:

```
<%=
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
CSV.generate do |csv|
  @persons.each do |person|
    csv << [ person[:name], person[:nickname] ]
  end
end .html_safe
%>
```

The solution you linked to does not work anymore with Rails 3 because all strings are considered unsafe by default, which was not the case in Rails 2.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I ran into the same problem.

Comment: Brilliant! Solved a headache.

Answer (score 0):

### Refactored

Benoit is absolutely correct and thanks for that tip. After looking at your code I see a much cleaner approach to generating your CSV as well, which I thought I would share for those landing here (like me!):

```
<%=
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
@persons.collect{ |person| [ person[:name], person[:nickname] ].to_csv }.join.html_safe 
%>
```

Essentially, you don't need all that CSV generate stuff. Ruby can take an `Array` and turn it into a CSV string, then just use a `collect` and `join` to put it all together nicely.

You can also do the following if you prefer having it on separate lines, which I do:

```
<% response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream' -%> 
<% @persons.each do |person| -%>
  <%= [ person[:name], person[:nickname] ].to_csv( row_sep: nil ).html_safe %>
<% end -%>
```

Here you'll need to use the `-%>` to ensure you don't get extra blank lines and you'll need to use the `row_sep: nil` option so that `to_csv` doesn't add a `\n` at the end of each line.

Anyway, hope that helps clean some people's code up.