# Generating CSV creating issues, as I have quotes or comma in data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

In my result.csv.erb, I have a issue with the csv being createdas within some of the columns in the result, I get data spillage.

I have a column called title which can be be of the form `Son's of fortune`, or `Love,Fear,Hatred`. In the first case, for some reason, I get &quot in my result. In the other, the data gets split by , as default :col_sep is ,.

```
<%- @results.each do |result| -%>
    <%- row = result.values -%>
    <%= CSV.generate_line row, :row_sep => nil, :quote_char => "'" %>
<%end%>
```

For eg-: The title was `Gas Shoe (Grey, Chestnut)` and the result spills into the other columns

```
title - &quot;Gas Shoe (Grey
seller -  Chestnut)&quot;
```

I am open to editing the data before insertion if absolutely necessary. So any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All strings in rails3 are unsafe by default, so you need to call #html_safe on your row. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358509/rails3-csv-putting-quotquot-instead-of-actual-quotes):

```
<%=
response.content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
CSV.generate do |csv|
  @persons.each do |person|
    csv << [ person[:name], person[:nickname] ]
  end
end .html_safe
%>
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried...I get undefined method for some reason. Is it because it's a .csv.erb file?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the advice on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values. There's no standard CSV format, but the section "Towards Standardization" gives some good advice. The parts that apply to you are:

- Fields containing a line-break, double-quote, and/or commas should be quoted. (If they are not, the file will likely be impossible to process correctly).
- A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters.

So if the field has commas, wrap it with double-quotes. If the field has a double-quote, replace it with two double-quotes. Fields with single-quotes should be wrapped in double-quotes, but otherwise do not need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove that from your result using `YOUR_STRING.gsub("&quot","")`

Comment: Better to call .html_safe as is done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358509/rails3-csv-putting-quotquot-instead-of-actual-quotes